# Serialization of Class that has serializable nested classes in it strange compilation error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I'm trying to learn some basics of boost serialization. So I followed [the tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html) and created simple `class A` and `class B` and `class C` that has `A a_;` and `B b_;` in it as private members.

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class A{
private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
                ar & a_;
        }

        int a_;

public:
        A(){ std::cout << "A constructed" << std::endl; }
        A(int a): a_(a) { std::cout << "A constructed with 'a' ==" << a << std::endl; }
};
class B{
private:
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
                ar & b_;
        }

        std::string b_;
public:
        B(){ std::cout << "B constructed" << std::endl; }
        B(std::string b): b_(b) { std::cout << "B constructed with 'b' ==" << b << std::endl; }
};

class C{
private:
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
                ar & a_;
                ar & b_;
                ar & d_;
        }

        A a_;
        B b_;
        double d_;

public:
        C(){  std::cout << "C constructed" << std::endl; }
        C(int a, std::string b, double d ): a_(a), b_(b), d_(d) { std::cout << "C constructed with 'd' == " << d << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    // create and open a character archive for output
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");

    // create class instance
    C c(15, "rock and roll", 25.8);

    // save data to archive
    {
            boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
            // write class instance to archive
            oa << c;
            // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }

    C c_recreated;
    {
            // create and open an archive for input
            std::ifstream ifs("filename");
            boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
            // read class state from archive
            ia >> c_recreated;
            // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

In IDEone live it is [here](http://ideone.com/2N1f3) with all strange and scary compiler errors. While on my VS2010 I got only 2 identical errors:

```
Error   2   error C2248: 'C::serialize' : cannot access private member declared in class 'C'
Error   3   error C2248: 'C::serialize' : cannot access private member declared in class 'C'
```

What have I done wrong, how can I make `class C` serializable after having `class A` and `class B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't `friend class boost::serialization::access;` for `B` and `C`.

Comment: after adding [here](http://ideone.com/2N1f3) it still does not compile on IDEone, why, does it mean this code will not compile on linux, how to fix it for IDEone compilation? compiled perfectly on my VS, thank you so very much!!!)))

Comment: @myWallJSON: Seems like Ideone only provides the headers of Boost, and doesn't have the compiled lib for stuff like Boost.Serialize. That's why the linker complains.